# Accessing request attributes in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I am practicing JSP with small programs and came across small issue.

I have my first jsp page with a form and a code that sets the request attribute.

```
<form action="process.jsp" method="post">

    User: <input type="text" name="userName">
    <br/><br/>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

</form>

<%request.setAttribute("sampleKey","myValue");%>
```

This is how my `process.jsp` looks like:

```
Welcome <%=request.getParameter("userName")%>
<br/>
The attribute is <%=request.getAttribute("sampleKey")%>
```

When I access first page and submit to process.jsp page then I was expecting the request attribute will have its value, but I am getting `null` here.

This is just a sample program for learning, I am aware that we should not use scriplets.

What is the issue here, can you please tell me?

Comment: When you navigate to a new JSP you hit the server first. Won't this destroy the request? You are saying "Give me something from the request" but you are doing so in the contents of a response.

Comment: Are both JSPs handling the same `request`? Are you sure?

Comment: I agree with @Takendarkk. When you submit the form, you create a new request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that when you submit the `<form>`, it makes a new `POST` request to *process.jsp* and hence any `request` *attributes* set before aren't available anymore. What you need is to use the `session` scope instead, which will keep its *attributes* across several requests coming from the same user.

So, in your JSP form a session attribute set as

```
<% session.setAttribute("sampleKey","myValue"); %>
```

can then be retrieved in your *process.jsp* as

```
Welcome ${param.userName}
<br/>
The attribute is ${sampleKey}
```

Comment: When we are supposed to make communication between tow jsp's `request` scope will not be available ?

Comment: No, unless the request is included/forwarded at server-side with a `<jsp:include>` for example. Anytime you ask the client to make a request, like a redirect, it will always be new. This is why we call HTTP a stateless protocol.

Comment: Or just include it as a hidden form field if it just needs to exist for the duration of that request.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in <% request.setAttribute("sampleKey","myValue"); %> this code because of request . use

instead of

and then you can get in process.jsp page by this type .

session.getAttribute("sampleKey");

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you are using html from to submit request to `process.jsp`. Hence your request attribute gets lost.

Option 1, Use `hidden` field in the same form and get it using `req.getParameter()`.

Option 2, Use `session` attribute instead of `request`.